Random class usage in Dart (Flutter)
I am working towards bringing a C# desktop application to mobile app in Flutter.
For this, I need to use a random number sequence. But since C# uses a different generator as compared to Dart, I am getting different list of random integers each time (even if the seed is same).
I use Random.Next(0, 24) in C# but in Dart, Random.nextInt(24) doesn't generate the same sequence .. has anyone faced this problem? If so, how to fix it?
In other words, is there any relation between the seed values of Dart and C# as I want the same value in both of the implementations?

If you want random numbers, why do you expect (or want) to get predictable sequences?

@Fildor because they are repeatable. The same generator with the same parameters and seed will produce the same sequence. This is a requirement when you want to reproduce statistics and data science results. Cryptographic RNGs aren't used in statistics for this reason

@MohammedZaidulHaq what's your real problem? Why do you expect completely different libraries and algorithms to produce the same random number sequence? Or that the same library will produce the same sequence? Cryptographic RNGs even use thermal noise from CPU sensors to ensure they don't produce the same sequence. Repeatability is actually a weakness, in engineering, statistics and cryptography. Repeatability is only needed in data science papers to allow others to reproduce results with a limited data set.

there any relation between the seed values of Dart and C# none whatsoever, because the algorithms are different, and even if the same algorithm was used, the parameters would be different. The algorithms change even between Dart and C# versions.

For example, Random random = Random(410); print(random.nextInt(10) in dart gives value of 3 but Random random = new Random(410); Console.WriteLine(random.Next(10)) gives the value 9.

We don't need examples. Why do you want repeatable sequences? It matters a lot. Either you're looking for the wrong thing that weakens security, in which case you should stop, or you need to find or write a library that implements the same algorithm and allows you to use the same parameters. OR generate a large set of numbers and use it in both applications

@PanagiotisKanavos, I am generating a sequence of 24 random numbers each time in C#. But the same numbers are not generated in Dart. That's my exact problem :) Hope it got clarified.

This is to maintain the decoding sequence in the original software same. This app is actually a License Generator for a main desktop application. Since, laptop is not easily accessible, i want to bring it to mobile

You keep repeating the same phrase. That doesn't make anything clearer. You don't grasp what random number generation is about or how it works. I suspect you study at a data science course otherwise you'd know that repeatability is a problem, not a feature. R and data science Python libraries are the only place where repeatability is desirable. Either that, or you're trying to build your own encryption based on repeatable sequences, which makes it trivial to break. Lots of algorithms were broken in the 2000s due to weak RNGs

@PanagiotisKanavos "because they are repeatable" - of course. My question was specifically aimed at why OP would have that requirement. And more so require two completely unrelated implementations to provide the same repeatable result.

Dart's own implementation changes and at first Random number generator is unbelievably bad. - that's the title of the GH issue, not my comment. If you look at the data you'll realize that the algorithm just shifted bits to the right. The current source shows it uses the Multiply with Carry algorithm first introduced in 1995.

"This app is actually a License Generator" - Then you should absolutely not use any pseudo random algorithm. Whenever money is involved you should be using secure algorithms, like repeatedly hashing a seed to generate a random sequence. But I would consult with an expert in cryptography to validate whatever scheme you come up with.

.NET on the other hand uses multiple algorithms and since .NET 6 uses the xoshiro256** algorithm created by the same guy that created MWC, 8 years later, for 64-bit systems.

@MohammedZaidulHaq license generator that's not how these work AT ALL. What you attempt was already broken in the 1990s. For starters, there are no licensing issues in app stores, which means you're trying to sideload. Second, license generators use public key encryption to encrypt and sign a license file/key so the application knows it actually came from the publisher. The license generator encrypts some data (eg CPU, disk serial, MAC address etc) using the publisher's private key. The  application decrypts the file using the public key and checks whether it matches the machine

BUT even that can be broken. Worst case, someone can install the app in a VM and control all possible parameters. That's why licensing is a constant problem, why game companies invest so much on this, why you need some online state and why App stores are so popular

You keep talking about OPs design without actually knowing anything about it. Fascinating. There is absolutely nothing wrong in using PRNG for licensing. In fact "repeated hashing a seed to generate a random sequence" is a PRNG. Also, it is not even clear what is the purpose of this PRNG, perhaps it has nothing to do with security. Maybe it is just some additional data in the license? Who knows? Again, fascinating.

@freakish if we didn't keep asking, we wouldn't know this is about licensing. It's the OP's job to post a clear question. Yes, it's fascinating how people expect good answers to unclear questions and then attack the people trying to understand the problem and help. Unless you disagree with you need to find or write a library that implements the same algorithm and allows you to use the same parameters. which was posted at least 15 minutes before your answered the same

@PanagiotisKanavos you literally learned nothing from "licensing" information. You generate information out of thin air and put words into OP's mouth. Yes, you could ask for more details, but decided to actually not to and make an arbitrary judgment. Is that the standard you work on? Yes, it is fascinating. Also, I don't see any other answer next to mine (including deleted), so I have no idea what you are talking about.

@MohammedZaidulHaq the xrandom package implements the xoshiro256** algorithm that .NET 6+ uses. You may be able to use it to produce the same sequence with this, although implementation differences can result in different sequences. Or you could try to replicate the Wikipedia C code in both languages, to ensure you have the same implementation

Those languages/runtimes use different algorithms for their built in PRNG (pseudo random number generator). In order to satisfy this requirement you will have to use the same algorithm on both sides. Either through some lib, or implemented manually. Which is not hard, assuming security is not a concern. For example linear congruential generator is very simple and often good enough.
If security is a concern, then you will likely need a cryptographically secure pseudo random generator, which are not that easy to implement manually. But still doable, for example I implemented manually ChaCha20 based CPRNG in the past. That being said it would probably be better to reuse some existing library. These will be of course significantly slower than non-cryptographic PRNG, often an order of magnitude or more. If that matters at all.
You may want to do a research on other (C)PRNG algorithms, depending on your needs. Either way you have to get rid of the default implementations (which often are not even specified, and may change from language/runtime version to version) and use something else directly.

That's worse than either choice. If you look at the sources you'll find that Dart uses MWC, C# uses xoshiro256 and guess what - both were created by the same guy!

@PanagiotisKanavos define "worse". It depends only on the requirements. Also, I'm not sure why it is relevant who created those algorithms.

Not at all - that's how RNGs are evaluated, by the length of the sequence, the correlation between numbers, statistical distribution, even spatial distribution. And LCG is worse than MWC which is worse than xoshiro. I actually took a course on systems emulation in 1996 which, it turned out, was all about RNGs and how systems responded to random input. Not what I thought at all. I actually had to implement the "new" MWC and show how it behaved in a graph

If you take 2 numbers at a time and plot them you'll realize that the "random" numbers in the simpler algorithms are actually drawn along slanted lines. A measure of quality is the distance between those lines. Algorithms that only use one previous number to generate a new one (like LCG) aren't great

@PanagiotisKanavos again: define "aren't great". You've missed the point, it doesn't matter as long as it satisfies requirements. As far as I know, LCG is still the default implementation of rand in libc. After 40 or so years. You know why? Because hardly anyone actually cares. Because it is good enough, and trivial to implement. As long as security is not a concern, which I already said in my answer. Also, don't treat OP like a child. OP can do research on the topic.

I didn't miss the point, I'm saying it's wrong, based on both engineering and academic standards. This isn't an opinion. Read (actually read) the Potential issues section in Wikipedia's RNG entry. Espectially the part Up until 2020, Java still relied on a linear congruential generator (LCG) for its PRNG,[6][7] which is of low quality (see further below). Java support was upgraded with Java 17.. You're arguing SQL string concatenation when people talk about server-bound parameters and SQL injection

@PanagiotisKanavos you are of course wrong. Java used 48-bit LCG, that's the reason they stopped using it. The 128-bit LCG passes virtually all statistical tests and is fast as hell. Don't talk about academic standards if you don't know this.
